# NodeJS del module's promise needs explicite function for promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, del

I don't understand why this del function needs a new function for its promise. Below is the full code. The problem is in the clean function.

```
gulp.task('styles', ['clean-styles'], function () {
log('Compiling less to css');

return gulp
    .src(config.less)
    .pipe($.less())
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version', '> 5%']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));

});

gulp.task('clean-styles', function (done) {
    var files = config.temp + '**/*.css';
    return clean(files, done);
});

gulp.task('less-watcher', function () {
    gulp.watch([config.less], ['styles']);
});

////////////////

function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));

    console.log(typeof done); // prints 'function'
    del([path]).then(done); // errors
}

function log(msg) {
    if (typeof msg === 'object') {
        for (var item in msg) {
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
            }
        }
    } else {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg));
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
[23:28:32] Using gulpfile ~/WebstormProjects/gulp-tutorial/gulpfile.js
[23:28:32] Starting 'clean-styles'...
[23:28:32] Cleaning: ./.temp**/*.css
function
[23:28:32] 'clean-styles' errored after 36 ms
[23:28:32] Error    
at formatError (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)    
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)    
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)    
at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)    
at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/user/WebstormProjects/gulp-tutorial/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)    
at /home/user/WebstormProjects/gulp-tutorial/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23    
at finish (/home/user/WebstormProjects/gulp-tutorial/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)    
at cb (/home/user/WebstormProjects/gulp-tutorial/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
```

If I change the code for the 'clean' function like this below, it strangely fixes the problem. Why does it reject one function but accept another?

```
function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));

    console.log(typeof done); // prints 'function'
    del([path]).then(function () {
        done(); // works!
    });
}
```

Even if I use a function that was assigned to a variable rather than being hoisted it still works. So why does it not accept the 'done' function in the promise. This is boggling my brain.

```
function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));

    console.log(typeof done); // prints 'function'
    var test = function () {
        done();
    }
    del([path]).then(test);
}
```

**----------SOLVED----------**

Thanks Johannes Merz for answering this for me. I thought of the 'done' function as being my callback but I was wrong. It belongs to gulp so to simulate the problem checkout the new 'clean' function below.

```
function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));

    del([path]).then(function (val) {
        console.log(val);
        done('Not null or undefined so this will fail it');
        // done(); but this would work!
    });
}
```

Basically the promise will pass an argument to the function used by the promise. This screws things up because the 'done' callback thinks that argument is an error message or object. This makes perfect sense to me now.

```
done(err);
```

So if 'err' is null or undefined we will have no problems. The problem is that the promise does not know this. The promise is passing a message, not an error, but the done function thinks its an error so it bugs out.

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Its because the del function resolves a promise with a value. Have a look at the docs, done is considered to be successful if its passed undefined:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#accept-a-callback

So you call `done('some value that isn't undefined')` if you pass done to the then block directly which is considered an error whereas you call `done();` if you wrap it in an extra function. Try

```
del([path]).then(function (delResult) {
    console.log(delResult);
    done(); // works!
});
```

to see whats returned.

Comment: Wow, that was confusing. I read this answer about 20 times trying to understand it. Concurrency and asynchronous problems always catch me. Thanks for the help!